# Android Studio not creating activity from event dispatch thread on arch linux

Tags: java, android, linux, android-studio, archlinux

I couldn't find any information on this error. I'm running Arch Linux 64bit and I've tried using oracle jdk 7 and 8 as well as open jdk and still have not been able to resolve this issue. When I create a new activity on my project, if I'm not running as root the application crashes. When I run android studio as root the app creates the activity but still throws this error.

```
12:28:34 PM Gradle sync started
12:28:37 PM Gradle sync completed
12:28:38 PM Executing tasks: [:app:generateDebugSources, :app:generateDebugAndroidTestSources]
12:28:41 PM Gradle build finished in 3s 524ms
12:29:36 PM Throwable
        Read access is allowed from event dispatch thread or inside read-action only (see com.intellij.openapi.application.Application.runReadAction())
        Details: Current thread: Thread[ApplicationImpl pooled thread 9,4,main] 1486871956
        ; dispatch thread: false; isDispatchThread(): false
        SystemEventQueueThread: Thread[AWT-EventQueue-0 1.3#AI-141.2135290, eap:false,6,main] 1522625013
```

Here is the only piece of information I could find on the matter but switching to openjdk 7 doesn't seem to work. Any suggestions?

EDIT: Using Android Studio 1.3.1

Comment: Q: What's your Android Studio version?  Is this link applicable: http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=56629?

Comment: I'm using Android Studio 1.3.1

Comment: Answered at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39828043/gradle-error-write-access-is-allowed-from-event-dispatch-thread-only-in-androi