# Failed to complete Gradle execution cause write access is allowed from event dispatch thread only

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle

when I open my android studio, after completing the Gradle build, i get the following error 
"Failed to complete Gradle execution

cause:

write access is allowed from event dispatch thread only"

what do I do ?

**Here is the picture of error message**

[image]

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39828043/gradle-error-write-access-is-allowed-from-event-dispatch-thread-only-in-androi

Comment: it is not working

Comment: @MikeM. its not working

Comment: does the Gradle build works from commandline?
also, take a look at `idea.log` (Help -> Show Log in Explorer) and look for similar error message there. It should be with a stacktrace there, attach it to the question,

Comment: See my answer from that link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39828043/gradle-error-write-access-is-allowed-from-event-dispatch-thread-only-in-androi/52089713#52089713

Comment: See my answer from that link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39828043/gradle-error-write-access-is-allowed-from-event-dispatch-thread-only-in-androi/52089713#52089713

Answer (score 1):

I closed the IDE, deleted the `.AndroidStudio3.0` folder in the user home and after i started it again that error disappeared. The IDE had also deactivated the android support plugin by itself.
I exported the settings before deleting the folder to override the defaults quickly after 'reinstall'.

After importing all settings the error reappeared so I repeated the delete operation and then imported the all settings except the `SDK settings` and made it work. It seems some of the settings were changed, preventing the IDE from functioning.

Answer (score 1):

I too faced the same problem, so I Invalidated cache and restarted. when restarts you will find the same problem, then click on Logcat you will find

**Please configure Android SDK**

then select your configuration what you used earlier as Oreo, Marshmallow, or others...

This worked for me.(Gradle Build Successfully).

Comment: it is better to explain the configuration in details that would help to solve the problem

Answer (score 0):

For me **File > Sync with file system** was fix.

Answer (score 0):

Simple goto File -> Project Structure -> SDK Location (in your Android Studio),
then check 'Use embedded JDK' checkbox and set JDK location to `'path to android studio'\Android Studio\jre`.

Answer (score 0):

Navigate as follows:
1.Click on 'File' then select 'Sync Project with Gradle Files'

This method worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

After spending 2 hours, I am able to fix this issue

> Open Logcat -> it shows "Please Configure Android SDK." Tapping Configure , it will open project structure, set source and target compatibility -> OK.

it will build gradle successfully and make project runnable.

Answer (score 0):

For me Project Structure ->JDK Location -> check on "Use embedded JDK" or use your own JDK
This method worked for me