# Android Studio not showing Inline Error

Tags: java, android, android-studio, error-handling, android-gradle-plugin

I am using Android Studio(3.0) to make an Android App. But suddenly the Android Studio has stopped showing inline errors where as there are still errors which are shown while building the app.

Till now I have tried the below solution

1) Clean Project

2) Rebuild project

3) Invalidate cache and restart

4) Check if the power save mode is on

5) Resync the Gradle

6) Delete the .gradle and .idea folder

But none of them have been useful. This problem has started suddenly.

Any help would be really appreciated.

Comment: Click on bottom right corner icon in android studio(probably a smiling face) and uncheck the Power Save Mode. Did you do that or the system power save mode?

Comment: @JacobCelestine Thanks for the reply and sorry for the delayed response. Yes I have Disabled the Power saver and also my system/laptop is also not in power saver mode. Any other suggestion?

Comment: Try running inspection manually with Inspect Code on the Analyze menu

Comment: @JacobCelestine Tried it. But it shows that scanned x files and no errors found. Where as I have some errors in the code.

Comment: Try this then:
BACK UP your project.
Delete all .iml files and .idea folder.
Relaunch Android Studio and import your project.

Comment: @JacobCelestine OK. Will try and update very soon.

Comment: @JacobCelestine It gives error "app.iml" not found.

Comment: Rebuild the project. Build -> Rebuild.

Comment: This is the error which is given `Error:Failed to complete Gradle execution. Cause:
Write access is allowed from event dispatch thread only` @JacobCelestine

Comment: refer this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39828043/gradle-error-write-access-is-allowed-from-event-dispatch-thread-only-in-androi

Comment: @JacobCelestine Now It is showing some errors such as repeated Variables but it is also showing errors for `android.os.Bundle` import and many other import also. But the situation is better than before.

Comment: that's out of this questions reach. You'll have to open another issue for those. Is your problem fixed? If yes I'll post the answer so can you just accept that?

Comment: @JacobCelestine Yes please post an Answer. You have helped me a lot till now. Will surely create a new Question and post the link. Please post an answer.

Comment: I've posted an answer. Please accept and upvote it and close this issue. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try running inspection manually with `Inspect Code` on the `Analyze` menu.

If that doesn't work then try doing this:

1. BACK UP your project.
2. Delete all .iml files and .idea folder.
3. Relaunch Android Studio and import your project

Comment: I have created a new question here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51771307/android-studio-showing-imports-error Can you please help.

Comment: I'll definitely take a look at it tomorrow :)

Answer (score 0):

In my case, deactivate "Power save mode" solve the problem.

In menu "File->Power Save Mode" (just in the end of menu, preview to "Exit" option)

Slds!